# How to Compute the ln of the GDP with only the growth rates

Tags: macroeconomics

I have an exercise where I was only given the growth rates of an economy for every year, starting in 1985 and ending in 2023. Using only this data, I was asked to compute the ln of the GDP for 1984. How can I compute this value?

Comment: If you only have the growth rates and no absolute data at all, then it clearly cannot be done: e.g.; starting from both 100 and 200 you can have 3% growth each year. Ask for clarification. Do they not specify one of the years as a base year perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

Giskard is correct in their comment.  Sounds like either the class or the professor is mistaken in their assessment of the question.  It could be there is one year of nominal data and the rest of the years are growth rates?